# Issue binding ZeroMQ to PHP In MacOS

Tags: php, error-handling, command-line-interface, zeromq, failed-installation

I am attempting to add the [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) extension's PHP functionality to my local server. I have successfully installed it however binding it to the PHP of my system has been a challenge.

I've attempted both the [PEAR/PECL](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) and [Github](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php) building methods however they all come down to this CLI Error:

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/zmq/zmq.c:31:
/private/tmp/pear/install/zmq/php_zmq.h:45:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [zmq.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

where can I generate and include this `php.h` file?

`php-v` shows: `PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )`

`phpize -v` shows: `grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:

Zend Module Api No:

Zend Extension Api No:`

Comment: Whats `php -v` and `phpize -v` show? You installed `php*-dev`?

Comment: check updated question @LawrenceCherone & for the life of me, i cannot find a straight forward guid to installing `php`7-dev` package

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when installing zmq on MacOS 10.14.3 Mojave. I'd done the followings and it's fixed.

1. install the command line tools if you haven't done so.

   xcode-select --install
2. install the header files

   cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
   open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Credit to @Steven [Installing xdebug on MacOs Mojave - 'php.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623108/installing-xdebug-on-macos-mojave-php-h-file-not-found)