# Installing xdebug on MacOs Mojave - 'php.h' file not found

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-mojave

I try to install xdebug on MacOs Mojave but get this error

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/xdebug.c:25:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
```

Command Line Tools are installed.

Answer (score 68):

I ran into this trying to compile xdebug on my system, I had to do the following to get it to work

0) Check that you have the file  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg on your system.

1) If not, install the command line tools (I had installed them at one point, but the files under /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ were missing so I must have deleted it...)

```
xcode-select --install
```

2) Reinstall the header files

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Credit to @donatJ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612102/649915

Comment: You, sir, saved my day. Do the headers and CommandLineTools get erased intentionally after updating to Mojave or is it a bug? I never had this issue before and I'm quite sure I didn't delete them.

Answer (score 14):

```
brew doctor
```

and then

```
brew link --overwrite php
```

helped me.

Comment: gave me Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php

Comment: using home-brew is okay if you are using hombrew, otherwise use the system via xcode-select --install (@steven's answer).  Personally, I am not a fan of hb.

Comment: `brew link --force --overwrite php72` works. Replace `72` with whichever version of PHP you would like to use.

Comment: `brew link --force --overwrite php@7.3` worked well in Catalina

Answer (score 10):

Headers aren't installed for Mojave.

To install the headers:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

I was having the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked, but I had to disable SIP first. Then install the headers, run PECL to install what I wanted and as the last step enable SIP again.